# For Loop with ifelse statement to create variable

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to use a for loop with a nested ifelse statement to generate an indicator variable in a dataframe. I'm fairly new to using for-loops however. Other questions I've found seem to be more complex than my dataset, so the answers haven't been ideal for my situation.

Essentially, I have survey recipients and names of their bosses, and I need to identify which recipients are also listed as bosses.

I have a vector of the boss names in which I know these names are also survey recipients.
For example (names have been changed):

```
bossrecip<-c("Tamira Hughes", "John Legend", "Robert Collins")
```

Then the column that includes the recipients full name, which I cleaned to be formatted in the same way as the boss names, is column "RecipientFullName" in my SurveyData.

```
RecipientFullName<-c("Gosha Jennings", "Robert Stew", "John Legend")
both_recip_boss<-0

SurveyData<-data.frame(RecipientFullName, both_boss_recip)
```

"both_recip_boss" is where I would like to put a 1 for if the recipient is also a boss, and keep it as a 0 if they are just a recipient

The for-loop I have tried that I think I am the closest with is

```
for (b in bossrecip) {
  ifelse(b==SurveyData$RecipientFullName | SurveyData$both_recip_boss==1, 
         SurveyData$both_recip_boss<-1, 
         SurveyData$both_recip_boss<-0)
}
```

I included the OR statement because I don't want the following names in b to overwrite the previous loop work. However, this just gives me one row with a 1, when I know there should be at least 91 ones in my full dataset. I'm sure I'm messing up something with the logic of for-loops, but I'm uncertain what it is.

I'd be very grateful for any advice and insight into what I am doing incorrectly. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, you can't put assignment _inside_ an `ifelse` expression, it's not like the `if` operator that allows code blocks. The `%in%` method demonstrated by stefan is the canonical, recommended, and fastest way to do what you need here.

Comment: One issue with the loop is on each iteration of `b`, the code executes SurveyData$both_recip_boss<-0` (or 1), which puts zeros in the entire column. You will need a different approach to perform a row-wise loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a loop. Using `%in%` you could do:

```r
SurveyData$both_recip_boss <- +(SurveyData$RecipientFullName %in% bossrecip)

SurveyData
#>   RecipientFullName both_recip_boss
#> 1    Gosha Jennings               0
#> 2       Robert Stew               0
#> 3       John Legend               1
```

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged the loop logic to show an approach.

However, `R` is a vectorized language, and much of the benefits in computation speed and codability come from vectorizing code or using the internal loop replacement functions (such as the apply family)

```
bossrecip<-c("Tamira Hughes", "John Legend", "Robert Collins") 

SurveyData<-data.frame(RecipientFullName=c("Gosha Jennings", "Robert Stew", "John Legend"),
                       both_boss_recip=0)

for (i in 1:nrow(SurveyData)){
  SurveyData$both_boss_recip[i]<-ifelse(SurveyData$RecipientFullName[i] %in% bossrecip, 
                                        1, 
                                        0)
}
SurveyData
```

> ```
>   RecipientFullName both_boss_recip
> 1    Gosha Jennings               0
> 2       Robert Stew               0
> 3       John Legend               1
> ```